# How to input data from a web page to Python script most efficiently

Tags: php, python, forms, cgi, web

How can I most easily input data from a web page and pass it to a Python script?

I've been reading here and on other forums a lot about Python in connection with php or cgi, or even Tornado, Django, etc but I am quite puzzled what is the best solution for me.

I have a Python script that grabs data from the web, generates .html pages etc - when being run there is just one

```
userIn=str(raw_input())
```

which makes the script gather data based on the input in the terminal. I now only want this input to be coming from some sort of

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="get">
Name <input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the file test.php I have tried passing the value in any kind (proc_open, exec...) but I do not seem to get the connection between python and this form, on top of that I am not sure what's the best idea to pass python's output (some debugging-errors etc) back to the web-interface?!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now managed it with the exec() command.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
exec("python mypythonscript.py ".$name, $output);
?>
```

Comment: You might want to use `escapeshellarg($name)`, or `implode(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', explode(' ', $name)))` instead of just `$name`.  See http://php.net/escapeshellarg for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To get a value from the form you could change `action="test.php"` to `action="/where_you_hooked_your_webapp"`.

The code of the application could be:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def handle_input():
    userIn = request.args.get('name', 'default name goes here')
    # grab data from the web, prepare data for html template, etc
    return render_template('user.html', user=userIn, data=data)
```

To find out how you can deploy it see [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) e.g., [Apache with mod_wsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

Comment: I just tried this in a simple setup but on clicking the submit-button I get the openfile-dialogue in Firefox (...you have chosen to open test.py which is a python script..... what should firefox do with this file?)...

Comment: @user1016690: What web-server do you use?

Comment: @user1016690: follow instructions from ["Apache with mod_wsgi"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/) link that I've provided above. Install [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) if needed. For debugging you could simply run the above app as a script (just add `app.run()` at the end) without any external web-server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php passthru() function for this.